# Manually throw Laravel ValidationException VS FormRequestValidationException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-exceptions

Is there any difference when I throw `ValidationException` **manally** and when `ValidationException` is **thrown by laravel from FormRequest**.

Following code will clear the problem

`UserController.php`

```
public function checkEmailExists(Request $request){
    try {
        $validation =  Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
        ]);
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            throw (new ValidationException($validation));
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception){
        return $exception->render(); //nothing is returned/displayed
    }
}
```

`Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    dd($exception instanceof Exception);
}
```

From the `UserController` I am throwing `ValidationException` **manually** and in `Handler.php` render method I am checking the `$exception` is an instance of `Exception`.
So If I throw `ValidationException manually` then

`dd($exception instanceof Exception); //gives false`

But when I use UserStoreRequest (FormRequest)

`UserController.php`

```
public function checkEmailExists(UserStoreRequest $request){
    //Exception thrown by laravel if validation fails fro UserStoreRequest
}
```

then in `Handler.php render()` method

`dd($exception instanceof Exception); //gives true`

1:- Why it has different behavior when I throw ValidationException manally and when ValidationException is thrown by laravel from FormRequest?

2:- If I throw ValidationException manually then in the catch block I get the following error

```
Error {#3627
  #message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::render()"
  #code: 0
  #file: "myproject/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php"
  #line: 33
```

Comment: Also, is this a Laravel 5 or Laravel 8 issue? Laravel 5 is a pretty old version, while Laravel 8 is pretty up-to-date, but you have this question tagged with both. Please clarify that 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
dd($exception instanceof Exception); //gives false
```

I'm pretty sure this is impossible. `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` extends directly from `Exception`. Your result might have to do with the catch block in `checkEmailExists`. Just so you know, you shouldn't have to catch such exceptions inside your controller, since that is what the Exception Handler is for (`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`).

There shouldn't be any different behaviour on how you use this, so let me show what ways you would use such validation:

#### Inside a controller function

Inside controllers you have the helper `$this->validate(...)` available:

```php
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'test' => 'required|integer'
    ], [
        'test.integer' => 'Some custom message for when this subvalidation fails'
    ]);
}
```

This automatically throws a `ValidationException` and therefore should get picked up by your Exception handler. Your Exception handler will then decide whether to return a JSON response with the validation errors (this will happen when a header `Accept: application/json` was used for instance) or flash messages to the session such that you can show them in your templates.

#### Outside controllers

Sometimes it is extremely handy to use the validation for things that run outside of your controllers. These could be jobs or background tasks for instance. In those cases, you would call it like so (its basically the thing what happens in the controller function):

```php
class SomeLibrary
{
    public function doSomething() {
        // Quickest way:
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($data, [
            'test' => 'required|integer'
        ])->validate();

        // Convoluted way:
        // (see your own code in the original post)
        
    }
}
```

This syntax basically does the same thing and also throws a `ValidationException`.

#### Throw a validation error immediately

Lastly, in some cases you want to immediately throw a validation exception without even needing to test any input, in that case you can use this to set the error messages:

```php
throw \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
    'amount' => 'The amount is not high enough'
]);
```

This will then follow the same route through the exception handler.